# Необходимо преобразовать двоичный код в байты Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст, обработка

Доброе утро! Недавно начал изучать Python, и поступила задача конвертировать символы (буквы и цифры), отрисованные в двоичном коде, в байты, т.е. чтобы буква или цифра выглядела в формате "bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,", ширина и высота букв - 48х72 пикселя, т.е. 6 строчек с отступами. Как можно это реализовать на питоне? Заранее спасибо.

Входящий (то, что получилось после конвертирования bmp-изображения в двоичный код)

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000011111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000001111111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000011111101111100000000000000000000
000000000000011111111001111100000000000000000000
000000000000011111110001111100000000000000000000
000000000000011111100001111100000000000000000000
000000000000011111000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Результат, который должен быть.

```
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000011, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00001111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00011111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx01111111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx11111101, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11111001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11110001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11100001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
```

[image: скриншот примера]

[image: цифра 1 вход]

Comment: Т.е. на входе такая картинка? Или на выходе? Распишите как-то почётче: вот такой вход, вот такое должно быть на выходе.

Comment: Приложите текст в вопрос ([edit])

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил изображение входа в вопрос. Т.е. второй скриншот - это то, что получается при конвертировании bmp-изображения цифры 1 в двоичный код, первый - то, что я делал сам руками и как это должно выглядеть по итогу.

Comment: @gil9red приложил.

Comment: ну так берите блоки по 8 битов и добавляйте 0b в начале, между блоками - запятые. Все.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru это, конечно, замечательно, только вот всё равно не слишком понятно, как это реализовать на питоне.

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас строки, вот и извлекайте из них куски с помощью срезов `s[k:k+8]`

Comment: можно использовать регулярку: `import re

p = re.compile('[01]{8}\n*')
res = "0b"+", 0b".join(p.findall(text))
print(res)`

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм:

- Считываем построчно
- В каждой строке считываем по 8 символов, к символам добавляем `bx`
- Выводим результат разделяя `,`

  - Для этого в `print` распаковываем список блоков через `*blocks`
  - Параметр `sep=', '` определяет как будут разделяться данные (по умолчанию это пробел)
  - Параметр `end=',\n'` определяет что будет добавлено в конце строки (по умолчанию это символ перевода строки `\n`)

Пример:

```
n = 8
for line in text.splitlines():
    blocks = [
        'bx' + line[i:i+n]
        for i in range(0, len(line), n)
    ]
    print(*blocks, sep=', ', end=',\n')
```

Входные данные:

```
text = """\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000011111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000001111111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000011111101111100000000000000000000
000000000000011111111001111100000000000000000000
000000000000011111110001111100000000000000000000
000000000000011111100001111100000000000000000000
000000000000011111000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
"""
```

Результат:

```
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000011, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00001111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00011111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx01111111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx11111101, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11111001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11110001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11100001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
```

Comment: Запятую в конце строк пропустили.

Comment: @GrAnd, спасибо, добавил :)

Answer (score 3):

Делается в одну строчку:

```
text = """000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000011111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000
000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000000
 поскипано много текста чтобы место не занимать 
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"""

res = "\n".join("bx"+", bx".join(line[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(line), 8))+"," for line in text.split("\n"))
print(res)
```

Результат:

```
D:\Programming\Python\1>python 8.py
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000001, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000011, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00001111, bx11110000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
bx поскипа, bxно много, bx текста , bxчтобы ме, bxсто не з, bxанимать ,
bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000, bx00000000,
```